# ArrayController deleting from tableview but not CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a pretty simple setup.

I have a NSTableView within my MainWindow.xib, whose value is bound to an ArrayController like so:

[image]

The ArrayController is setup like this:

[image]

[image]

I have a TestModel.xcdatamodeld which contains one entity, Test, with one attribute, a `body` with type of `string`.

I then have my window set up simply like this, with a textfield and two buttons to add and remove from the array controller:

[image]

When I add or remove any entry into the tableview, it works fine. But when I close and restart my app, those changes aren't synced to the core data.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Edit: I'm using Magical Record, too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you save changes with the context?

Something like:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, btw, I'm using Magical Record which might complicate things?

Comment: try to generate a simple project with core data, see what code it generates. if you use Magical Record, see how you can save the context. basically, the savings are done in memory first, but in order to make them persist, we need to save to context